# Recommendation for exercises one can do during Shin splints

Tags: exercise, rehabilitation, shins

Please recommend some exercises which I can do if I've got shin splints. I want to keep my body fit during my recovery, so any exercise is a welcome. I don't have access to a pool or a bicycle so that cuts my options. However I can afford a gym membership for some weight training.
Thank you.

Comment: Shin splints usually occur after exercise, and normally don't last very long. How long does yours last? It's a bit unexpected that someone would have a need to collect a list of exercises to do while recovering from it. Why not just stick to upper body workouts until it subsides?

Comment: It's the first time I've got them and they've kept on coming and going,however i didn't rest enough. I've read from multiple sources that it takes a month or above to heal properly. A month for me Is a big break hence the asked list.